# problem with uploading and downloading xml document from Datastore using google app and python

Tags: python, xml, google-app-engine

i am creating one xml document in my google app and storing it as blob while fetching back from datastore how do i convert it to again xml doc

```
class xmlStore(db.Model):  
 xmlRef=db.BlobProperty()
```

creating xml doc like this:

```
docRef=Document()
fp=docRef.createElement("Client")
fp.setAttribute("ID","21783")
docRef.appendChild(fp)
```

storing to datastore:

```
x=xmlStore(xmlRef=str(docRef))  
x.put()
```

while retriving back:

```
result = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM xmlStore").fetch(1)
```

while printing on webpage:

```
for response in result:
 self.response.out.write(response.xmlRef)
```

its giving me `xml.dom.minidom.Document instance at 0x6a2bddb0b5aef438`
how do i get back it in xml..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Python's documentation about `xml.dom.minidom` [toxml method](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.Node.toxml).

You say:

> its giving me xml.dom.minidom.Document
>   instance at 0x6a2bddb0b5aef438

Call the .toxml() method of that object.

Comment: stefansw thanks for your reply but to use that method i want xml document which i am not able to get when i am retriving back from datastore

Comment: as i am storing it as Blob in datastore

Comment: I edited my answer. But you still haven't accepted any answers to the questions you asked on stackoverflow. You should.

Comment: i got it i was storing  it as string instead of that it need to be converted to xml and after that need to store it..

Comment: There is the outline of a check mark next to my answer and also next to the other answers of the questions you have asked (find them through your profile). Click on it to mark the answer as accepted if you think the answer deserves it.